# Standard for Android Activities

Tags: android

My app has a creation page and an edit page. These two pages are almost exactly identical, save the difference you can't edit without first creating the page. It's working perfectly fine, except it seems a little redundant have two separate activities with the same actions.

My question is, what is the standard/best approach to this situation. Should I create a new class, from which both these classes could access methods from or could it be one activity? Also, there is some amount of calculations, (a small series of random number generators) being carried out, should this be running on a separate thread? Or is it fine running on the main thread?

An example of what I have is kind of like android contacts app, you can create new contact and you can also edit that contact, which is essentially the the create new contact page.

Comment: you can make static final variable to identify if its for create or edit page

Comment: What do you mean? Are you suggesting I use one activity?

Comment: yup. and before you call the activity, include a bundle to identify user action. edit or create

Comment: Right right, alright, thanks, I guess I'll use one activity then!

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1:

Have a Base Activity that extends Activity. 
Then add all the common code like inflation of layout, some logic, life cycle handling etc. 
Then create 2 classes like CreatePage and EditPage.  These two new classes will extend the Base Activity. 
Just handle the little variations in xml page dynamically here at runtime. Maybe in onStart(). 
This approach show cases basic OOPS of 1 parent Activity and multiple children.

Approach 2:
Have a Base Activity, and put create page and edit page as Fragments. 
Just replace the fragments on your activity according to your program flow.

P. S. My answer may be a little abstract since your question is generic :)

Comment: Yeah, it's alright, I understand what you're saying. I just wanted ideas on an approach, since I didn't know what the "standard/best" approach was. Do you think your approach would be better than what Randyka suggested with just having one class? With an if statement to behave differently depending on what you clicked? Since I don't do that much design this isn't something I've had to think about before and thank you for your input!

Comment: Something that Randyka has suggested isn't a solution. Always look for solutions and not fixes or patch work. That spoils programming ethics.